# Android Real-Time Navigation using Mapquest Open Guidance

Tags: android, eclipse, navigation, gps, mapquest

I am intending to extract the maneuverType (For e.g. Turn left or turn right) using Mapquest Open Guidance. May I know how do I extract the data from mapquest in real time?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since you ask, but maybe I can help you if it is still a problem to you.

I've a demo app in a github repo wich gets guidance information (also routing) from MapQuest. You can checkit out here: https://github.com/sebasira/Android-RouteWebService

Best Regards!